# How to sum the total amount for the last 12 months using parameters

Tags: sql, parameters, sum

I want to SUM up the last 12 months values from a sql query.

The problem is to sum up the last 12 months, instead of taking just the whole year.

So when I SELECT March 2000 as default in my parameter, 

 I want the query to SUM up: from March 1999-March 2000.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(sales) as totalsales, year_month
FROM Total_Sales
WHERE 
(year_month = @year_month)
GROUP BY Name, year_month
```

Thanks for any help!

--EDIT--

```
SELECT Name, SUM(sales) as totalsales, year_month
FROM Total_Sales
WHERE 
(year_month >= @From) AND 
(year_month <= @To)
GROUP BY Name, year_month
```

Added this after suggestions from "Steve Morgan" 

Can we add a average for the last 12 months somehow without selecting 12 months in the parameters.
Letting the "@From" parameter decide on start value. Something like: AVG(@From -12 months)??

Thanks again for the help!

--EDIT 2--

The **ROW_NUMBER()** function is very handy to solve this problem.
My query looks like this now:

```
SELECT  Name, SUM(sales)
FROM    
(               
SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY year, year_month)
, Name
, sales = SUM(sales)
FROM     Total_Sales ts
WHERE
(year_month>= @From) AND 
(year_month<= @To)
GROUP BY
Name
, year
, year_month
    ) ts 
WHERE
rn <= 12    

GROUP BY
Name
```

Comment: What type of the year_month field?

Comment: year_month is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Comment: Is there also a month or date field?

Comment: Your solution isn't quite what Lieven gave you.  Try it with dummy data spanning `2010-01` to `2011-12` for one name, and `2011-01` to `2011-12` for another name, then run your query for `2010-06` to `2011-05`.  I do not believe that it will give you the results you are looking for.  Whatever solution you adopt, you must put conditions on *both* the Year and Year_Month fields.

Comment: @Dems - Ok will try this. Made the change that the year_month field is created by an UPDATE using the "year" & "month" from the table itself.
so it looks like this now:
2000_01, 2000_02 etc.

Comment: If you're going to change the schema, you may be better advised to make the field a DateTime with a name such as MonthStart.  The logic will then become Much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is longer than Steve Morgans, but is designed to allow the optimiser the ability to use any existing INDEX on the `year` and `year_month` fields.  This is only relevant if you have a relatively large table as it is designed to efficiently know which records can be skipped.

(It also assumes MS SQL Server, but the logic is applicable to other RDBMSes.)

```
DECLARE
  @DateParam AS DATETIME
SELECT
  @DateParam  = '2011 June 01'

;WITH MyTable (Name, Year, Year_Month, Sales) AS
(
             SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 1, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 2, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 3, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 4, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010, 4, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 5, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010, 5, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 6, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010, 6, 10
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 7, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010, 7, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 8, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010, 8, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010, 9, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010, 9, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2010,10, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010,10, 10
                                       UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010,11, 10
                                       UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2010,12, 10
                                       UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2011, 1, 10
                                       UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2011, 2, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2011, 3, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2011, 3, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2011, 4, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Jane', 2011, 4, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2011, 5, 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2011, 6, 10
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Rod', 2011, 7, 10
)

SELECT
  Name,
  Year,
  Year_Month,
  SUM(sales) AS Total_Sales
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
   (Year = DATEPART(YEAR, @DateParam)     AND Year_Month <= DATEPART(MONTH, @DateParam))
OR (Year = DATEPART(YEAR, @DateParam) - 1 AND Year_Month >  DATEPART(MONTH, @DateParam))
GROUP BY
  Name,
  Year,
  Year_Month
```

Notes:
1. This will give the results for the 12 months up to and including June 2011
2. No data prior to July 2010 will be included
3. The gap for Rod's data won't cause Note 3 to be breached
4. Jane's missing data in May 2011 and June 2011 won't cause Note 3 to be breached
5. The formulation of the WHERE clause will allow INDEXes to be used

Comment: +1. If OP returns, he would do well to make this the accepted answer.

Comment: Kind to say, but I just hope he doesn't use what he posted in his last edit.  *That* certainly won't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from your example how year_month is stored, which makes it difficult to decide if it lends itself to being queried this way.

In such cases, I use what I call a relative month, which I calculate as

```
(year - 2000) * 12 + (month -1)
```

So, January 2000 is Relative Month 0, February 2010 is Relative Month 121, etc.

This is easily convertible to/from an Year and Month using SQL Server Scalar Functions and easy to query using >, <, etc.

Edit:

Just seen your comments about what year_month is and also that you have a year. A scalar function to calculate a relative month value from your year and year_month columns will work for you.

Then you can do:

```
where
    dbo.GetRelativeMonth(year, year_month) >= @startRelativeMonth
    and dbo.GetRelativeMonth(year, year_month) < @endRelativeMonth
```

Though it's more efficient to add a relative_month column to your table and calculate the value when you write the record.

Edit 2:

You asked how GetRelativeMonth works, so here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRelativeMonth] 
(
@Year int,
@Month int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result int
SELECT @Result = (@Year - 2000) * 12 + (@Month - 1)
RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: As you are calling a user defined function on the table's values, this will normally blind the optimiser to the existing indexes.  That said, it certain Does work.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I prefer to add a relative_month column.

Comment: How does the GetRelativeMonth function work?
I´m using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you could use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to concoct a subset of your data from wich you can select the final result.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  Name
        , SUM(sales)
FROM    (               
            SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year, Year_Month)
                    , Name
                    , sales = SUM(sales)
            FROM    @Total_Sales ts
            WHERE   (YEAR(@Param) <= ts.Year AND MONTH(@Param) <= ts.Year_Month)
                    OR (YEAR(@Param) < ts.Year)
            GROUP BY
                    Name
                    , Year
                    , Year_Month
        ) ts 
WHERE   rn <= 12        
GROUP BY
        Name
```

#### Test Data

```
DECLARE @Param DATE = '05-01-2011'
DECLARE @Total_Sales TABLE (
    Name VARCHAR(32)
    , Sales INTEGER
    , Year_Month INTEGER
    , Year INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO @Total_Sales VALUES 
    ('Malcolm X', 1, 1, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 2, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 3, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 4, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 5, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 6, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 7, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 8, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 9, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 10, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 11, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 12, 2011)
    , ('Malcolm X', 1, 1, 2012)
    , ('Ben Hur', 1, 2, 2012)
```

Comment: Would you not need DESCs in the ORDER BY of the PARTITION?

Comment: @Dems - a bit late for a response but no. Descending ordering would in fact give wrong results.

Comment: Sorry, mis-read the query.  You have the @Param on the left of the `<=`, and I just skimmed it and assumed it was on the right.

Comment: Note about this solution: It will return the last 12 year/month combinations that have data.  If one or more months don't have any records in the table, you will still get 12 results, even if they span more than 12 months.  => Ensure you have values for every month, even if the value is 0 :)  [And don't allow an @param prior ro the first month's data.]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the BETWEEN function? where YourDate BETWEEN minValue AND maxvalue

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, SUM(sales) as totalsales, year_month 
FROM Total_Sales 
WHERE year_month = DATEADD(MONTH,-12,'31-March-2000') 
GROUP BY Name, year_month
```

Try something like that.